# ImportError: No module named 'helper'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

My file layout is

```
C:\Fourier-Recovery
C:\Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\
C:\Fourier-Recovery\main_2d.py
C:\Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\network\
C:\Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\network\layers\
C:\Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\network\model.py
C:\Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\network\layers\helper.py
```

This layout is also described in following pictures.

When I at 19th line when executing following script, `main_2d.py`, I running a error `ipdb> ImportError: No module named 'helper'`.

[image]

So here is my file layout:
The root is `Fourier-Recovery`, where the `main_2d.py` resides:

[image]

Inside the `cascadenet`, I have `network` and `util`

[image]

Inside `network` I have `layers`

[image]

Inside `layers` I have all the files like following:

[image]

Here is the code in **__init__.py** in the `Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\network\layers`

[image]

So I went to the line of code where error occurs, went into `Fourier-Recovery\cascadenet\network\models.py`, and I see following import code:

[image]

So if I comment out:

```
import cascadenet.network.layers as l
```

the error would be gone. So since there is a `helper.py` inside the layers folder, I am not sure why the error occurred because it seems it has all the dependencies needs. I am using Python 3.5 on Windows 10. Please give some hints. I am very confused at this point.

I am not sure if I provide sufficient information for you guys, but if there is something you need but I am not aware, please let me know.

Comment: so what's the code in `cascadenet.network.layers`?!

Comment: What's the actual traceback?! so many pictures of folders...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the second last picture shows the files in thecascadenet.network.layers

Comment: Exactly, so `__init__.py` there. That's the *code*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I added one more picture showing whats inside __init__.py, is that what you need?

Comment: Strange ... that one should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `simple.py`, the `helper.py` was referenced, originally looking like this:

```
import theano.tensor as T
import lasagne
from lasagne.layers import Layer
from helper import ensure_set_name
```

So I added a leading dot infront of helper like this:

```
import theano.tensor as T
import lasagne
from lasagne.layers import Layer
from .helper import ensure_set_name
```

, and the complain is gone.